# Android custom adapter

Tags: android, database

i want to create a custom adapter in order to have a clickable button in every list item.
My problem is that i m getting the data from a database and i dont know how to present them in the list using my custom adapter.This is my adapter code:

```
public class Adapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    final Drawable delete;
    private ImageButton imageButton2;

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    private int favoriteListRow;

    public Adapter(Context ctx, int favoriteListRow, Cursor cursor,
            String[] columns, int[] to) {
        super(ctx, favoriteListRow, cursor, columns, to);

        mContext = ctx;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);

        delete_btn = ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.delete);

        DB entry = new DB(ctx);
        entry.open();
        cursor = entry.getData();
        columns = new String[] { DBHelper.NAME, DBHelper.NAME2 };
        to = new int[] { R.id.textView01, R.id.textView02 };
        entry.close();

    }

    public View getView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

        TextView name_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView01);

        int nameCol = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.NAME);

        String name = cursor.getString(nameCol);
        name_text.setText(name);

        TextView name2_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView02);
        int theCol = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.NAME2);

        String the = cursor.getString(theCol);
        the_text.setText(the);

        imageButton2 = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);
        imageButton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Button pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

            }
        });

        return v;
    }



}
```

And then from my main activity i m calling the adapter :

```
Adapter adapter;

ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Are you having any issues? It seems you are on right track.

Comment: yes,as you see my code now i m getting this error java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams

Comment: is it right to read my database data in the adapter class?or i should better read them in my main?

Comment: That is not good option, but not related to the issue you are having. It seems something wrong with your inflater. Read this link http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2011/01/31/android---create-a-custom-multi-line-listview-bound-to-an.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try initializing your Layout Inflater using this line instead

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
  (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Comment: i replaced that and i m not getting this error.But i m still have no result presenting in my list

Comment: Looks like you didn't initialize your Adapter before setting it